# invalid binary issue on itunes ios

Tags: ios, itunes

I am uploading app to app store.

Before uploading app, I am validating app and validation goes successful.

After that I am submitting app to store successfully.

But app doesn't show in iTunes account.
Now when i go to prerelease it says that **invalid binary**.

[image]

## UPDATE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode and go to Build Setting,
Please enable 64 bit Architecture in your project.
And set Standard Architecture.

[image]

Comment: It shows me same values as yours, i have added 1 more image. Check it.

Comment: Check image in UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Then Upload new Build version and Do not break your internet connection while you uploading.